# Batch file to move bottom folder into specified location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory structure which contains files organized into folders by an associated ID

```
..\abc\STORAGE\123
..\abc\STORAGE\234
..\xyz\STORAGE\345
..\xyz\STORAGE\456
```

I want all of the bottom subfolders, and all their contents, to be copied into a new directory such that afterwards I will have:

```
..\SomeNewDir\123
..\SomeNewDir\234
..\SomeNewDir\345
..\SomeNewDir\456
```

How should I accomplish this, using a batch script?

Comment: Your title says `move` and your question says `copy` so it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Test this: launch it in the folder that holds the `abc` and `xyz` folders.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do xcopy "%%a\storage\*.*" "c:\somenewdir\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "sourceRoot=%cd%"
    set "target=d:\test"

    for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
        set "bottom=1"
        for /d %%b in ("%%~fa\*") do set "bottom="
        if defined bottom (
            echo move "%%~fa" "%target%"
        )
    )
```

This will search the last directory in each sub branch of indicated source, independtly of name, and move (when the output to console is correct, remove the `echo`) the subdirectory to the target folder